# Hyperlinks in Windows Update window not working?

Tags: windows-update, hyperlink

The actual links in the Windows Update window to open the relevant Knowledge Base article have stopped working. They still look like links, but they don't do anything any more.

[image: Example of link in Windows Update]

This started happening (or not happening!) during the last Windows Update (around 2010-10-23). At the time I believe the first link worked okay and all subsequent links did not. In the recent Windows Update (today) no links work.

I can copy and paste the text of the link into the browser and it will work fine.

Web-like links from all other applications work okay.

---

**Dec 2010** - Windows Update links still do not work. I guess this must be *something* specific to my machine as I've not seen it reported anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be to do with Firefox (which *was* my default browser). Having changed my default browser to Google Chrome the links in Windows Update now work OK. If I change the default browser back to Firefox the links stop working again.

It is possible that the time when the Windows Update links stopped working coincided with a Firefox/extension update - but I can't remember for sure. I have come across [another user in the Firefox Support Forum with a similar problem](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/753531) after a Firefox update - links in MS Outlook stopped working.